# What is the call for the "lp filename" command in linux in a c program?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I want to use the above command in a c program in linux.

I have searched so far that there are system calls and exec calls that one may make in a code. Is there any other way using exec or system commands?
Using the system command isn't an ideal command for a multi-threaded server ,what do you suggest?

Comment: just do system("lp filename")

Comment: Are you asking whether this will work? Have you considered trying it?

Comment: You're invoking the `lp` command with an empty environment. That may or may not cause problems. But as "that other guy" asked, did you try it before asking whether it will work?

Comment: I am asking if the above code would work properly if not then do you know any simpler way of invoking a print command within a c program? . I really want to avoid forking and childs.

Comment: @Goldriver do you know [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: There is not necessarily a one-to-one correspondence between commands you can type into your shell and available C library routines.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you have `lp` installed in this path. (Using `which lp` in the terminal).

You may want to understand the `lp` command. It's a classic unix command to send data to the "line printer", but it works with e.g. `.pdf` files too nowadays, depending on your printer system. However, it isn't necessarily installed. Sometimes, `lpr` may work better, too.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_%28Unix%29

The second part is about executing unix commands. `system` is the easiest (also the easiest to introduce a security issue into your program!), using `fork` and `execve` is one of a number of alternatives (have a look at `man execve`).

Comment: i actually tested the lp command from my linux terminal and i was successfully getting prints but i wanted to know how i can use this command in my c program.

Yeah,it seems that system is the easiest but someone mentioned that it would slow down my program or hang my code in the above my comments.

Comment: To understand the two, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461936/system-vs-execve

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code is ok. It will print the file named `filename` provided that the `lp` is found at `/usr/bin` and the `filename` file exists. You can add checks for that if you want your program to report if something went wrong, other than that it will do exactly what you expect.

Doing `system("lp filename");` would work if you don't mind your program blocking after that `system()` call and until `lp` finishes.

Comment: It wouldn't be ideal for a multi-threaded server right?
I don't want my program to go in block state after getting the system command.
I want it to go back in listening state after it sends out the system command as i am implementing a multi-threaded server.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing. Can i pass a char array to a system call in my C program? like the following: char filename[1024]:"/home/user/Desktop/texts/hello1.txt" system("lp filename")

Comment: no, you need `snprintf` for that, something like `char command[SOME_LARGE_ENOUGH_VALUE]; snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "lp %s", filename); system(command);`.

Comment: i see, great! .There is another thing pertaining to the fork+exec thing ,such a statement is only necessary when you have multiple clients accessing the printer right?. I mean to say without fork  execve will still work fine?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with that, you use it if you want your program to execute the `lp` command, and continue executing, `fork()` creates a new process which is then replaced by `execv()`, so the original process continues execution normally, there is also `popen()` wich also allows communication with the child process.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) (instead of [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)). But you always need to fork a process (both `system` and `popen` are calling [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)). BTW, if you have a CUPS server you might use some HTTP client protocol library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) but that is probably inconvenient. Better `popen` or `system` an `lp` (or `lpr`) command.

BTW, printing is a relatively slow and complex operation, so the overhead of forking a process is negligible (I believe you could do that in a server; after all people usually don't print millions of pages). Some libraries might give you some API (e.g. [QPrinter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html) in Qt).

Notice that the `lp` (or `lpr`) command is not actually doing the printing, it is simply interacting with some print daemon (`cupsd`, `lpd` ...) and its spooling system. See e.g. [CUPS](https://www.cups.org/). So running the `lp` or `lpr` command is reasonably fast (much faster than the printing itself), generally a few milliseconds (certainly compatible with a multi-threaded or server application).

Quite often, the command passed to `popen` or `system` is constructed (e.g. with [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) etc...), e.g.

```
  char cmdbuf[128];
  snprintf (cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "lp %s", filename);
```

but beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) (think about `filename` containing `foo; rm -rf $HOME`) and of [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)

Of course, notice that library functions like `system`, `popen`, `fopen` are generally built above existing [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: Great Answer Basile!

I couldn't up-vote you because of the damn no for reasons down-votes which took down my user rating as i am a relatively new user so i can't vote.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing.

Can i pass a char array to a system call in my C program?

like the following:
char filename[1024]:"/home/user/Desktop/texts/hello1.txt"
system("lp filename");

Comment: @goldriver No, you have to form the whole command in the char array. eg: using `sprintf` and trhen "system" the char array.

Comment: @Jasen: never suggest `sprintf` but only `snprintf` (or `asprintf` if available)